# Trying to understand mocking google sign-in for Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, testing, mocking, google-signin

What I'm trying to do is test our sign-in widget for widget tests and later, integration testing and E2E testing.

So I have the following two mocks.  They both seem to require each other to work.

google_sign_in_mocks 0.2.1
https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_mocks

firebase_auth_mocks 0.8.1
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_mocks

What I don't understand is *how* to use them.  I'm going through the docs and examples, and I don't get it.

For instance, I am looking at the **google_sign_in_mocks** example and I don't understand where **MockGoogleSignIn**, **googleSignIn** and **.authentication** comes from.

I'm reading additional docs like https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage, but it feels like things are spiraling out of control.

Can someone help explain some of this for me?

Comment: Did you manage to do it? If yes, how?